# Iterators to arrays of different sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, iterator

The following code compiles fine on my system:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<std::array<int, 5>::iterator,
                           std::array<int, 7>::iterator>::value, ":(");
```

Is that behavior guaranteed by the standard? Is the iterator type independent of the array size?

If it is guaranteed, is there any way to abstract from the element type and ignore the size?

```
template<typename T, size_t n>
void foobar(std::array<T, n>::iterator it)
```

That is, is there any way to write the above array-specific code without mentioning the size `n`?

Note that I do not want to resort to `T*`, even though in release mode the iterator probably is a `T*`.

Comment: What's wrong with `template<typename Iterator_type> void foobar(Itearator_type it)`?

Comment: @Lol4t0 It's too general and doesn't satisfy my thirst for knowledge?

Comment: I mean, if code works for _given_ iterator, why should one impose artificial limitation? This 2 comments connected only to the last section of your question, of cause.

Comment: @FredOverflow ...but it is exactly the way you should do it. The declaration with e.g. `RandomAccessIterator` as template type argument will do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed. Each array type `array<T, size_t>` has a nested member typedef named `iterator` whose type is implementation defined.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no guarantees. The standard just says

```
typedef implementation-defined    iterator;
```

The iterator type could be a plain pointer, a class that is a member of the `array`, or a separate class wrapping the plain pointer.

If it is a member class, it *will* depend on the array size. Otherwise likely not.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is make it a bit more generic. Why do you only want to allow iterators from a `std::array`?

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foobar( Iterator it )
```

In the second piece of code, the type `T` and size `n` are in a non-deducible context. Conceptually multiple `std::array` types could have the same `iterator` type, or as you mention it can just be `T*`, and it would be impossible to find what possible `std::array` had a `T*` as `iterator`

Comment: In fact the *actual* answer is even *simpler*: *"No, this is not guaranteed by standard."*